# JSF não encontra ID de componente

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

Tenho algo como

```xhtml
<p:panelGrid id="tabelaUm">
    <h:form id="formUm" rendered="#{condicao ? true : false}"/>
    <p:commandButton action="#{condicao = false}" update="formUm, formDois"/>
</p:panelGrid>
<p:panelGrid id="tabelaDois">
    <h:form id="formDois" rendered="#{condicao ? false : true}"/>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Quando tento acessar a página, uma exceção `FacesException` é lançada:

> Cannot find component with expression "formDois" referenced from "formUm:j_idt185".

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: A pergunta ésta muito objetiva, tentarei dar uma dica no mesmo nível. Tenta isso:  `update="formUm,:form: formDois"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por estarem em form's diferentes, o `CommandButton` e o **formDois**, a **Search Expression** que usou não é válida.

O **Search Expression Framework** é o framework que o Primefaces usa para localizar componentes na árvore, seja através do atributo `process` ou do `update`.

Ele aceita algumas regras, como:

1. @this
2. @form
3. @parent
4. @all
5. @none

E outros...

Além de alguns modificadores como o ":", que define a hierarquia.

No seu caso a regra deveria ser:

```
update=":formUm, :formDois"
```

Se o `CommandButton` está dentro do `formUm` então ficaria:

```
update="@form, :formDois"
```

Colocando o ":" no começo quer dizer que é para começar a busca a partir do `ViewRoot`.

Lembrando que seu `commandButton` precisa estar dentro de um `form` e não pode haver `form's` aninhados.

Algumas referências:

1. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/search.xhtml
2. http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2740